# Como eu desenvolvo um metodo de um classe arvore binaria de busca

Tags: c++

Como eu desenvolvo um metodo de um classe arvore binaria de busca, pra retornar elementos multiplos de 5 em uma lista? C++

Comment: Informa mais detalhes de seu problema, ou qual ponto você está tendo problemas, pois sua pergunta me parece muto superficial, tente adicionar mais detalhes para que alguém possa lhe auxiliar mais facilmente.

Answer (score 1):

Arquivo `Binarysearchtree.h`

```
  struct tree_node
  {
    tree_node *left;
    tree_node *right;
    int data;
  };
class Binarysearchtree
{
private:

    tree_node *root;
public:
    Binarysearchtree();
    bool isempty() const;
    void inorder ( tree_node * );
    void printinorder();
    void preorder ( tree_node * );
    void printpreorder();
    void postorder ( tree_node * );
    void printpostorder();
    bool binarytreesearch( int );
    void insert ( int );
    void remove ( int );
};
```

Arquivo `binarysearchtree.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Binarysearchtree.h"
using namespace std;

Binarysearchtree::Binarysearchtree()
{
    root = 0;
}
bool Binarysearchtree::isempty() const
{
    return root == 0;
}
void Binarysearchtree::insert ( int d )
{
    tree_node *t = new tree_node;
    t->data = d;
    t->left = t->right = 0;
    tree_node *parent = 0;

    if ( root == 0)
        root = t;
    else
    {
        tree_node *curr;
        curr = root;
        while ( curr )
        {
            parent = curr;
            if ( d > curr->data )
                curr = curr->right;
            else curr = curr->left;
        }
        if ( d > parent->data )
            parent->right = t;
        else parent->left = t;
    }   
}
void Binarysearchtree::remove ( int d )
{
    if ( root == 0 )
    {
         cout << "Tree is empty. No removal. "<<endl;
         return;
    }
    if ( !binarytreesearch ( d ) )
    {
         cout << "Value is not in the tree. No removal." << endl;
         return;
    }
    tree_node *curr;
    tree_node *parent;
    tree_node *parent1;
    tree_node *temp;
    parent = 0;
    parent1 = 0;

    curr = root;

    while ( d != curr->data )
    {
        parent = curr;
        if ( d > curr->data )
            curr = curr->right;
        else
            curr = curr->left;
    }

    if ( curr->data == d )//it is leaf node
    {
        if ( curr->left == 0 && curr->right == 0 )
            {
                if ( parent != 0 )
                {
                    if (  parent->right  != 0 && ( parent->right )->data == curr->data ) 
                    parent->right = 0;
                    else parent->left = 0;
                    delete curr;
                }
                else
                {
                    root = 0;
                    delete curr;
                }
            }

    else if ( curr->left != 0 && curr->right == 0 )
    {
        if ( parent != 0 )
        {
            if ( parent->right != 0 &&  ( parent->right )->data == curr->data )
                parent->right = curr->left;
            else 
            parent->left = curr->left;

          delete curr;
        }
        else
        {
            root = curr->left;
            delete curr;
        }
    }
    else if ( curr->left == 0 && curr->right != 0 )
    {
        if ( parent != 0 )
        {
            if ( parent->right != 0 &&  (parent->right)->data == curr->data )
            parent->right = curr->right;
          else
              parent->left = curr->right;
          delete curr;
        }
        else 
        {
            root = curr->right;
            delete curr;
        }
    }
    else if ( curr->left != 0 && curr->right != 0)
    {
        if ( parent == 0 )
        {
            temp = curr->right;
            if ( temp->left == 0 )
            {
                temp->left = curr->left;
                curr->right = 0;
                root = temp;
                delete curr;
            }
            else
            {

                while ( temp->left != 0 )
                {
                    parent = temp;
                    temp = temp->left;
                }
                if ( temp->right == 0 )
                    {
                        parent->left = 0;
                        temp->left = curr->left;
                        temp->right = curr->right;
                        root = temp;
                        delete curr;
                    }
                else
                {
                    parent->left = 0;
                    parent->left = temp->right;
                    temp->left = curr->left;
                    temp->right = curr->right;
                    root = temp;
                    delete curr;
                }
            }
        }//end parent == 0
        else // parent != 0
        {
            temp = curr->right;
            if ( temp->left == 0 )
            {
                curr->right = 0;
                temp->left = curr->left;

                if ( parent->left != 0 && ( parent->left)->data == curr->data )
                { parent->left = 0; parent->left = temp; }
                else { parent->right = 0; parent->right = temp; }
                delete curr;
            }
            else
            {
                while ( temp->left  != 0 )
                {
                    parent1 = temp;
                    temp = temp->left;
                }
                if ( temp->right == 0)
                {
                    parent1->left = 0;
                    temp->left = curr->left;
                    temp->right = curr->right;
                    if ( parent->left != 0 && ( parent->left )->data  == curr->data )
                    {   parent->left = 0; parent->left = temp; }
                    else { parent->right = 0; parent->right = temp; }
                        delete curr;
                }
                else 
                {
                    parent1->left = 0;
                    parent1->left = temp->right;
                    temp->left = curr->left;
                    temp->right = curr->right;
                    if ( parent->left != 0 && ( parent->left )->data == curr->data)
                    { parent->left = 0; parent->left = temp; }
                    else  { parent->right = 0; parent->right = temp; } 
                        delete curr;
                }
            }
        }//end paret == 0
    }
  }
}
void Binarysearchtree::printinorder()
{
    inorder ( root );
}
void Binarysearchtree::inorder( tree_node *p )
{
    if ( p != 0 )
    {
        inorder(p->left);
        cout << " " << p->data << " ";  
        inorder ( p->right );
    }
}
void Binarysearchtree::printpostorder()
{
    postorder ( root );
}
void Binarysearchtree::postorder ( tree_node *p )
{
    if ( p != 0 )
    {
        if ( p->left )
            postorder ( p->left );
        if ( p->right )
            postorder ( p->right );
        cout << " " << p->data << " ";
    }
}
void Binarysearchtree::printpreorder()
{
    preorder ( root );
}
void Binarysearchtree::preorder ( tree_node *p )
{
    if ( p != 0 )
    {
       cout << " " << p->data << " ";
       if ( p->left )
        preorder ( p->left );
        if ( p->right )
        preorder ( p->right );
    }

}
bool Binarysearchtree::binarytreesearch( int d  )
{
    bool found = false;
    if ( root == 0 )
    {
        cout << "tree is empty";
    }
    tree_node *curr;
    tree_node *parent;
    parent = 0;
    curr = root;
    while ( curr != 0 )
    {
        if ( d == curr->data )
            {
                cout << "found";
                found = true;
                break;
        }
        else if ( d > curr->data )
        {
            parent = curr;
            curr = curr->right;
        }
        else
        {
            parent = curr;
            curr = curr->left;
        }

    }
    if ( !found )
        cout << "not found";
    return found;
}
```

Arquivo `Source.cpp`

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Binarysearchtree.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Binarysearchtree b;
    int ch,tmp,tmp1, temp2;
    while(1)
    {
       cout<<endl<<endl;
       cout<<" Binary Search Tree Operations "<<endl;
       cout<<" ----------------------------- "<<endl;
       cout<<" 1. Insertion/Creation "<<endl;
       cout<<" 2. In-Order Traversal "<<endl;
       cout<<" 3. Pre-Order Traversal "<<endl;
       cout<<" 4. Post-Order Traversal "<<endl;
       cout<<" 5. search " << endl;
       cout<<" 6. Removal "<<endl;
       cout<<" 7. Exit "<<endl;
       cout<<" Enter your choice : ";
       cin>>ch;
       switch(ch)
       {
           case 1 : cout<<" Enter Number to be inserted or enter to quit: ";     
                    cin >> tmp; 
                    b.insert( tmp );
                    break;
           case 2 : cout<<endl;
                    cout<<" In-Order Traversal "<<endl;
                    cout<<" -------------------"<<endl;
                    b.printinorder();
                    break;
           case 3 : cout<<endl;
                    cout<<" Pre-Order Traversal "<<endl;
                    cout<<" -------------------"<<endl;
                    b.printpreorder();
                    break;
           case 4 : cout<<endl;
                    cout<<" Post-Order Traversal "<<endl;
                    cout<<" --------------------"<<endl;
                    b.printpostorder();
                    break;
           case 5:
                    cout << "enter number for search ";
                    cin >> temp2;
                    b.binarytreesearch( temp2 );
                    break;
           case 6 : cout<<" Enter data to be deleted : ";
                    cin>>tmp1;
                    b.remove(tmp1);
                    break;
           case 7 : system("pause");
                    return 0;
                    break;
       }
    }
}
```

Fonte: [Aqui](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=14308&lngWId=3)